# CloudKit not work when Apple review

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cloudkit

I have used CloudKit in my app, but it had been rejected by Apple with reason because of CloudKit not work, but I have tested that build via TestFlight and it's worked in my end. 
Any body faced this issue and any advice for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible variants about why your application is being rejected. In iTunes Connect I would ask Apple Review Team about more details. And then please update your question if you could not solve it alone.

Comment: Thank you Nikita, Don't know why this morning, my app had been approved, God bless me haha. My issue have solved. Thanks!!!